# i want to Logout from Twitter in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to add logout from twitter. i am also logged out but when am trying to login again then this is not opening from twitter login page and showing old user id and username.i used this code to logout.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *user_ID=[defaults objectForKey:@"USER_ID"];
[[[Twitter sharedInstance] sessionStore] logOutUserID:user_ID];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,this code is from Twitter Docs.

```
TWTRSessionStore *store = [[Twitter sharedInstance] sessionStore];
NSString *userID = store.session.userID;
[store logOutUserID:userID];
```

Comment: i user this one also but it it not showing twitter login time main view where pop up apper integration.